# Git update the branch

Tags: git

I have a master branch from which I created branch 1 and 2. The branch 1 I made some change and committed and merged with master. Now that I have already taken a new branch 2 the change made to master is not available there. But I need the change in 1 to continue development of branch 2.

How do I do it?

Update: Some changes has been made in branch2 already. Otherwise I would have just deleted that branch and created branch2 again from master. I need branch2 change as well as the branch1 change that has already been merged to master.

Comment: Have there been any other changes to `master` between creating `2` and merging `1` back to master? There is a number of ways you can get those changes into `2` but the exact way depends on what other changes have been made. You could possibly merge `1` into `2`, merge `master` into `2`, cherry-pick the exact commits you want to `2` or perform an interactive rebase. It's hard to say which way would be the best with just the information you've provided so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can rebase your `branch2` on top of `master` (which already includes changes from `branch1`).

Using [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase master
```

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar what did you see as an error? The rebase is supposed to *replay* `branch2` on top of `master`, which already includes `branch1`: that shouldn't "not work".